Creating a function to disable / enable the key list
I want to create a function to disable/enable the key list, but I do not know in what form to record the keyboard shortcut and how to use them.
toggleKeys() {
    myKeys := ["h", "j", "k", "l"] ; ... "+h", "+j", "+k", "+l" ...
    For i, v in MyKeys
        Hotkey, GetKeyName(v), toggle
}

I'm writing a script for komorebi, so that the keyboard shortcuts are like in tmux

You can use #HotIf to only use hotkeys when a specific condition is met. Most common usage is by combining it with WinActive() to only use hotkeys when a specific window is active. So use AHKs builtin WindowSpy to find whats your windows handle. Here's the solution using #HotIf in v2:
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

#HotIf WinActive("ahk_exe notepad.exe")
h::+h
j::+j
k::+k
l::+l
#HotIf

